# controlling border length

Tags: html, css

i want to limit the **border length** applied to a div element(or any HTML elements) . For example consider a div of *width 100px*, is there anyway to apply the border to *only 40px* width itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a child div of the appropriate width to do that. For example:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="border"></div>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

with:

```
#outer { width: 100px; padding-top: 0; }
#border { width: 40px; border-top: 1px solid black; margin-top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a nested div or a narrow image as background.

Try not to add a div only to display the border, always try to be semantic. Probably your design need a supplementary section.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding another `<div>` you can simply use a the pseudo selector `:before` and `:after`:

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
div:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    height: 1px;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Zb2/).

Comment: Instead of using `background-color` to imitate the border, you can, of course, use `border` and set `height: 0;`. Probably the better solution.